# Redirect JTextField to system.in

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm working on a text based game. I created a JFrame with a JTextArea for the console output and a JTextField as a command line. 
The problem is that I can't get the text from the TextField and pass it to my parser. What changes should I make to this part of the parser so that I can make work?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        inputLine = reader.readLine();
    } catch (java.io.IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("There was an error during reading:" + exc.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Please explain - JTextArea for the console output and a JTextField as a command line, are they not same?

Comment: Please provide the error you are receiving

Comment: `I can't get the text from the TextField`, why can't you use the `getText()` method of `TextField`

Comment: No they are not the same. The output appears as text in the TextArea while the TextField is being used for the user input.

I know that I can get the text with the .getText() method but I don't know how I can pass it to the parser, since InputStreamReader isn't accepting strings.

Comment: Your title and question body say different things. If you use a text field for input, get it with `textField.getText()`. If you use a text area for output, use `textArea.append(...)`. What parser?

Comment: Add a ActionListener to JTextField, when triggered, use the getText method to read the text from the field and write out the System.in

Comment: I'm finished with the output part. Now I only need to pass the string to the parser. The parser used to get input by the console using the System.in but now I want it to get it from the TextField.

@MadProgrammer Yes, that's the way I'm doing it but as I said my problem is that I don't know how to pass the string to the System.in

Comment: Don't you want to write to the output stream?  `System.in` is for reading

Comment: @MadProgrammer All I want is the user to put a command in the TextField, which I should get, probably with a KeyListener and the .getText method, and then pass this command to my parser. The parser used to get the command through the console, using the code that I posted above but now I want to change it. The problem as I mentioned is that I don't know how should I modify the above code so that it can get the ,getText string.

Comment: So can't you pass the text from the textfield directly to your parser instead?

Comment: Parser's method that uses the system.in is in a loop so that it can get command after command so I think it's difficult to pass him the string directly, unless I can make it stop until it gets an input. That's why I asked if there is a way to redirect it straight to the system.in method, but since I can't find anything I think I'll better change my game's structure and pass the string directly as you said. Thank you for your help